# Create Multiple Columns from Two Column Excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, transpose

Here is what I have:

```
column a      column b
32            apple
32            pear
32            banana
33            soap
33            tea
```

Here is what I would like:

```
32      apple      pear      banada
33      soap       tea
```

I don't want to use VBA or anything complex, just a simple formula please!

Comment: Generally speaking, you should leave your data as is.  It is already Excel-friendly and will work well with formulas like `COUNTIF/S`, `SUMIF/S`, `SUMPRODUCT`, etc.  It is also in a desirable format for using a pivot table if you'd prefer.

Comment: Hello. This does not work with a pivot table as there are close to 3000 rows and when a pivot table is used there is many gaps in the resulting table. I need to compile a CSV file from the two columns and as such, this is why I need it setup this way. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can select the vertical range in Column B that you wish to be
 separated

- right click and "Copy"
- select the place you wish to paste it horizontally
- right click and choose "Paste Special"
- in the dialogue box that appears, select "Transpose" near the bottom, and press OK.

It should paste your selection into consecutive horizontal cells. Then you can go back and delete any extra rows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello. I know this, however, this does not help me. If you look at the example given this is what I need. Transpose through paste special only gives me 2 rows.